# How to add any method in UDO SAP Business one 9.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sapb1

I have created my new UDO in SAP B1 Client. Then I opened this UDO in Visual Studio. I added button to this UDO for testing. And click saveToDatabase, it is updated. But When I write any code in new button and save it, it is not work in SAP B1. UDO opens, button appears but it doesn't work when I click it. How Can I solve it? Or is there any other way adding code in UDO?

Comment: I wanna say that if you want custom code, you would need to actually package the changes as an add-on. You can run it in debug mode (if your Visual Studio is in the same environment as your B1 program), but if you want other users able to use it, you would need to package it up.

Comment: Ok, I understaned but I can't open UDOform1 When I run Visual Stuio. Show() Method doesn't work with UDOform, how can I solve it?

Comment: What I do is generate the UDO form and then create a user form copying the xml of the UDO form. You need to change some values but after that it works perfect. Experiment.